# Can not read properties of null (reading 'username')

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to find a user by id but its erroring.

Here is my code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'whois',
  execute: (client, message, args) => {
    const userId = args[0];
    const member = message.guild.members.fetch(userId);
    message.reply(`Thats ${member.user.username}!`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is due to the fact you're not awaiting the fetch returned from `<GuildMemberManager>#fetch`.

Change your code to the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'whois',
  execute: async (client, message, args) => {
    const userId = args[0];
    const member = await message.guild.members.fetch(userId);
    await message.reply(`Thats ${member.user.username}!`);
  }
}
```

[documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch)